# Problem with the continuous equivalent of Newton's method optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, dynamic, nonlinear

In the article [Fixed-Time Stable Gradient Flows: Applications to Continuous-Time Optimization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9113452) I found an interesting formula and its properties. The screenshot of the page from the article I was led below.

In another article [A Continuous Version of Newton's Method](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07468342.1997.11973888?journalCode=ucmj20), I found a similar formula, but in contrast to the first article, where the ratio of the gradient $G$ to the hessian $H$ is used, i.e. $G/H$, this use $f(x)/G(x)$. Screenshot from the article I also led below.

**Problem:** I decided to "play" with formula

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-(\frac{d^2f}{d^2x})^{-1}\frac{df}{dx}$

and function $f(x)$

$f(x)=e^{-(x-x_*)^2}$

and found that none of them work as it should (you need convergence from the starting point $x(0)$ to the point $x_*$).

Below I give code from Mathematica and what happened.

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xstart = -1, xend = 1}

f = Exp[-(x[t] - xend)^2]

E^-(-1 + x[t])^2

sys = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == -(D[D[f, x[t]], x[t]])^-1 D[f, x[t]], 
   x[0] == xstart}, {x}, {t, 0, 500}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], xend}, {t, 0, 25}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

**Question:** What's wrong with this formula or where did I make a mistake?

I will be glad any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We know for Newton's method, the initial guess can be critical. Try e.g. `x[0]==0.3`.

Comment: Newton's method is_descending_ for convex functions.

Comment: Your function has a maximum. Are you sure the technique is not looking for a minimum?

Comment: The method does not work, even if I "reverse" the functions, making the maximum of the minimum. But when choosing the starting point in sufficient proximity to the extremum, the system works.

Answer (score 5):

Consider your equations:

```
f = Exp[-(x[t] - xend)^2]
x'[t] == -(D[D[f, x[t]], x[t]])^-1 D[f, x[t]]
x[0] == xstart
```

If we evaluate this:

[image]

If we now calculate x'[0]:

[image]

(* -2/7 *)

As this is the initial slope and is negative, the solution must fall at x==0, it can not increase. Maybe your equations are wrong.

Comment: No, i guess. These are rather disadvantages of this method.